# select anyone optgroup at the same time in custom javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/4HJd4/34/)

I have two types of optgroup with option.

I need to validate between two groups. How to do that ?

**Case 1**

If i select the A optgroup.simuultanseuly i cant able to select optgroup B

i need to select any one. can't select both at the same time.

**Javascript**

```
$('#select').change(function () {
    var selectedOption = $('#select option:selected');
    var label = selectedOption.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
    var selectText = selectedOption.text();
    if(label == 'A'){   $('.selectoption').val(label); }
    var length = $(this).find(':selected').text().length;

    $('')

    if(label== 'A'){
        alert('check');
    } else {
    alert('no test');
    }

   // if (length < 2) {
        //$(this).find(':selected').text(label + ' - ' + selectText);
    //}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`element.prop('disabled', boolean)`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/) to disable / enable the form elements.

You can disable the other `optgroup` using the above technique like this:

```js
$(function(){

  $('#select').change(function () {
     $('optgroup').prop('disabled', false);
      $('optgroup').removeClass('selected');
      var selectedOption = $('#select option:selected');
      $(".selectoption").val(selectedOption.closest('optgroup').attr('label'));
      
      selectedOption.closest('optgroup').addClass('selected');
      var label = selectedOption.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
      var selectText = selectedOption.text();
      $(this).find('optgroup').each(function(i) {
       if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
         $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
         $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        }
      });
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" multiple style="height:150px;width:150px;">
    <optgroup label="A">
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option value="">2</option>
        <option value="">3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="B">
        <option value="">4</option>
        <option value="">5</option>
        <option value="">6</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<input type="text" name="selectoption" class="selectoption" value="" />
```

Comment: As you said, you can select only A elemets if A options are selected! According to that I've answered!

Comment: i dont need A elements now i need to select B elements then A elemts should be disabled vice versa..

Comment: @QuestionUser - See my updated answer. I've updated as according to you!

Comment: @QuestionUser - I've updated the code too! Check the code.

Comment: cant able to select the option B once i clicked the option A

Comment: I think this is what you wanted! You've said earlier that if you select A, B elements should be disabled & if you select B, A elements should be disabled!

Comment: how to deselect B and i need to select A

Comment: I am not getting you right. Be clear what you're trying to ask. You can disable the options via `prop()` method, see my code!